# Display a Response Data of an API in to RecyclerView in Kotlin

Tags: android, json, kotlin, android-recyclerview

**My Adapter Class**

```
class LocationAdapter(private var locationList: ArrayList<LocData>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<LocationAdapter.LocationViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): LocationViewHolder =
        LocationViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.recycler_row_list, parent, false)
        )

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: LocationViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val location=locationList[position]
        holder.id.text = location.id.toString()
        holder.locName.text=location.name.toString()
        holder.address1.text = location.address1.toString()
        holder.address2.text=location.address2.toString()
        holder.city.text = location.city.toString()
        holder.state.text= location.state
        holder.country.text = location.country.toString()
        holder.zipCode.text=location.zipCode.toString()
        holder.headOffice.text = location.headOffice.toString()
        holder.deleted.text=location.deleted.toString()
        holder.orgName.text = location.organizationName.toString()
        holder.orgId.text=location.organizationId.toString()
    }
    override fun getItemCount(): Int = locationList.size

    class LocationViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
    {
        val id: TextView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewid)
        val locName: TextView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewlocationName)
        val address1: TextView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewaddress1)
        val address2: TextView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewaddress2)
        val city: TextView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewcity)
        val state: TextView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewstate)
        val country: TextView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewcountry)
        val zipCode: TextView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewzipCode)
        val headOffice: TextView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewheadOffice)
        val deleted: TextView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewdeleted)
        val orgName: TextView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.textVieworganizationName)
        val orgId: TextView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.textVieworganizationId)
    }

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    fun setLocationData(locationList: ArrayList<LocData>)
    {
        this.locationList=locationList
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

**Main Activity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var locationRepository: LocationRepository
    private lateinit var locationViewModelFactory: LocationViewModelFactory
    private lateinit var locationViewModel: LocationViewModel
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var postAdapter: LocationAdapter


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        initRecyclerView()

        locationRepository = LocationRepository()
        locationViewModelFactory = LocationViewModelFactory(locationRepository)
        locationViewModel =
            ViewModelProvider(this, locationViewModelFactory).get(LocationViewModel::class.java)

        locationViewModel.getPost()

        locationViewModel.myResponse.observe(this, Observer {
            postAdapter.setLocationData(it as ArrayList<LocData>)
            it[0].locationId?.let { it1 -> Log.d("main", it1) }
            recyclerView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        })
    }

    private fun initRecyclerView() {
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
        postAdapter = LocationAdapter(ArrayList())
        recyclerView.apply {
            setHasFixedSize(true)
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
            adapter = postAdapter
        }
    }
}
```

**Base Url**

```
object Url {

    const val url="https://106.51.52.207:8092/hrdome/"
}
```

**API**

```
interface Api {
    @GET("locations/getAll/24")
    suspend fun getAllLocations(@Query("locations") locations:String,): List<LocData>
```

**My JSON Data**

> {"status":true,"statusCode":200,"statusMessage":"ok","errorMessage":null,"data":[{"id":37,"state":null,"country":null,"address1":null,"zipCode":null,"headOffice":false,"address2":null,"city":null,"locationName":"holi","deleted":false,"organizationId":24,"organizationName":"JPMC"},{"id":38,"state":"AndhraPradesh","country":"India","address1":"MVP","zipCode":"530034","headOffice":false,"address2":null,"city":"Pune","locationName":"MVP office","deleted":false,"organizationId":24,"organizationName":"JPMC"}]

Need to display the "data" to my recycler view.

**my Data Class**

```
data class LocData (
    val id: String?,
    val locationId: String?,
    val country: String?,
    val name: String?,
    val address1: String?,
    val headOffice: String?,
    val address2: String?,
    val zipCode: String?,
    val city: String?,
    val deleted: String?,
    val organizationName: String?,
    val organizationId: String?,
    val state: String
)
```

Comment: Describe the issue

Comment: Hi Vivek Gupta
I'm trying to display the JSON Response data into Recycler view, I'm not getting any error but not the data wanted.
Our data is as follows,
{"status":true,"statusCode":200,"statusMessage":"ok","errorMessage":null,"data":[{"id":37,"state":null,"country":null,"locationName":"holi","address1":null,"address2":null,"city":null,"zipCode":null,"headOffice":false,"deleted":false,"organizationId":24,"organizationName":"JPMC"}]

In this i need to display texts which is under "data":

Comment: it[0].locationId?.let { it1 -> Log.d("main", it1) } is this log printing right info?

Comment: Nope, It was edited and replaced by id. Still wasn't able to display the data.
I tried to use log.e as well but not fruitful.

Comment: so, i guess, you aren't getting any data in the observer hence no data in the recyclerview. Show code where you are retrieving the data (viewmodel's code and the data source)

Comment: I'm trying to capture my response in mainActivity only, 
locationViewModel.myResponse.observe(this, Observer {
            postAdapter.setLocationData(it as ArrayList<LocData>)
            it[0].locationId?.let { it1 -> Log.d("main", it1) }
            recyclerView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        })

Comment: What are you assigning "myResponse" ?